# Convert Array to String Nesc

Tags: c, nesc

I want to convert an array of `uint8_t` to a `uint32_t` in **NesC**.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about NesC, but should each `uint8_t` in the source array be converted to a single `uint32_t` in the destination? Or should four `uint8_t` in the source be combined to a single `uint32_t` in the destination?

Comment: yes this is the idea. Like in C, I want to convert an integer array to one integer.

Comment: So, uh, how come you've commented that both Joachim's and my answers are helpful, when they do *different things*? Confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that i were found is the use of the function :

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

There is also the function :

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

In my code i use memcpy and it works fine. Thanks to all people that answer my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a single `uint8_t` in the source to a single `uint32_t` in the destination, it's actually very simple. Just create the destination array, and copy the values in a loop:

```
uint8_t *source;
size_t   source_count;  /* Number of entries in the source */

uint32_t *dest = malloc(sizeof(*dest) * source_count);
for (int i = 0; i < source_count; i++)
    dest[i] = source[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title mentions strings, but your question text doesn't. This is confusing.

If you have four 8-bit integers, you can join them into a single 32-bit like so:

```
const uint8_t  a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
const uint32_t big = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
```

This orders them like so, where letters denote bits from the variables above:

```
0xaabbccdd
```

In other words, `a` is taken to be the most significant byte, and `d` the least.

If you have an array, you can of course do this in a loop:

```
uint32_t bytes_to_word(const uint8_t *bytes)
{
   size_t i;
   uint32_t out = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
   {
     out <<= 8;
     out |= bytes[i];
   }
   return out;
}
```

The above assumes that `bytes` has four values.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I used a rong words to explain my need. This can help me a lot. Thank you very much